# Selected features disappear from map from ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working with the Javascript API version 3.19. I have a feature layer used to display aerial images footprints. This feature layer is configured to fetch all the features to display at once based on an area of interest and a definition query using the mode FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION.

My issue is the following: the data is displayed properly at first, but if the user pans outside of the area of interest, all the selected features will disappear from the map, and will never show up again when I visit that part of the map again. From the debugger, I can see those features are still in the graphic collection associated with the feature layer, but they will not show up on the map. I have tried the following when the extent of the map changes:

Iterate through the features / graphics and call the method draw and / or show()

Call FeatureLayer.redraw()

Call FeatureLayer.refresh()

That still does not do the trick. Calling FeatureLayer.selectFeatures displays the data again but using that would make the code more complex than I suspect it needs to be. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

The issue goes away when I am not setting the symbols of the selected graphics from a configuration file. The symbol definition is causing the issue. I am not sure why yet, but at least I know the culprit. Issue solved.

Comment: Confirmed. That graphic definition which I was loading from a json string was causing the issue. The issue was just not happening until the graphic had to be redrawn.